# SSAS Restore Task Hangs in SQL Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas

We're running SQL 2014 SP1 and have an SSIS job that does a full process of an SSAS cube. There's two subsequent tasks once the processing is done: 1 to take a back of the cube and then it will restore that backup over the cube that is linked to our front end reporting solution. The issue is that the restore will just hang and never complete. I can't find a spid to kill that one process, nor can I just stop Analysis services on the server. My only way to kill that hanging job is to kill the server.  Is there a way to find the spid of that process so I can just kill it or another solution I could try?

Comment: Why not try to synchronize the SSAS databases instead of full backup, full restore.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://geekswithblogs.net/ManicArchitect/archive/2008/01/22/118801.aspx

You can use DMVs to find the session and then xmla or ascmd to kill it.  ascmd is very useful for this kind of stuff, so I highly recommend it anyway:

http://www.codeplex.com/SqlServerSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4000